# Underwater positioning system (swimming pool)

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, proximity

I'm making a few experiments with a quite simple rover car I made using Arduino UNO and a few spare parts. Just for the heck of it I made it waterproof and now I want to toss it in my pool to make some underwater exploration. Maybe I'll fit some scrubers under it to make it easer to clean the floor.

My problem is: my rover navigates on its own, avoiding walls and objects using an ultrasonic sensor. But underwater the speed of sound goes up, and different qualities of water make it even harder for this system to work. Sometimes the pool is full of particles, and the scruber will probably worse the water quality around the robot.

My question is: what kind of system is better to navigate underwater, simply avoiding walls? The current behavor (on dry ground) is to turn to the right and go on when it finds a wall, I would like to keep this behavior, but underwater. As it's a simple toy, I'm hardly willing to spend a hundred bucks on a fancy laser proximity sensor, neither I need to map the entire pool with a single pulse, it should be a simple wall avoiding system.

Thank you!

Comment: bumberswitches (i.e. limit switch with long stiff wire attached).

Comment: Infrasound could work. Same as ultrasound but low frequency audio instead.

Comment: Infrasound works well on large distances. I doubt it's of any use inside a regular pool.

Comment: Try it out with the ultrasonic system.  Other than the speed issue (which will result in things appearing closer than they are) the ultrasonic system should work fine in the water, even with floating particles.

Comment: @IgorStoppa You don't have an Olympic size pool in your garden?!

Comment: @Majenko: I suppose with Olympic you refer to the real thing, as in "swimming place near Mount Olympus", colloquially known as Aegean Sea. Because that's what would probably make the use of infrasounds possible. No, I don't have that in my garden.

Comment: @IgorStoppa Imagine the pool parties you could have...

Comment: @IgorStoppa Also, just because infrasound has a large range doesn't mean it's useless for shorter range. It doesn't travel any faster than ultrasound, it can just travel much much further. It still echoes off close things. The only thing you have to watch is that your sound production period is shorter than the period of your shortest desired echo, and with infrasound that is limited by the wavelength of you want to produce at least one full cycle of the audio signal. So you choose your frequency to suit. You may well end up with a frequency that isn't strictly infrasound, but sure isn't ....

Comment: ... ultrasound. Low audible frequencies, for instance . The theory of operation is just the same

Comment: Have a look at this, form the Robotics site, perhaps: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7564/how-to-localise-a-underwater-robot

Answer (score 1):

How about a tilt switch?  The bottom corners of a pool should allow the car to ride up the wall a little, when it tilts past 5 or 10 degrees, turn it left.....